# Can't print data from 2 layer ArrayList using Freemarker

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I'm using freemarker 2.3.23 in eclipse to generate reports.
Below are the code for Data-model:

```
ArrayList<Cell> namelist=new ArrayList<Cell>();         
Cell cell1=new Cell();      
cell1.data.add("element1");         
namelist.add(cell1);
Cell cell2=new Cell();
cell2.data.add("element2");
namelist.add(cell2);
data.put("namelist", namelist);
```

Code for class Cell:

```
public class Cell {
    public ArrayList<String> data;
    public Cell(){
        data=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Code for template:

```
  <#list namelist as name>
    <#list name.data as element>
      ${element}
    </#list>
  </#list>
```

But got error stack as below:

> FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or
>   missing:
>   ==> name.data  [in template "report.ftl" at line 33, column 16]
>
> ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
>   ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default
>   value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if
>   myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only
>   cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression,
>
> ### use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>
> ### - Failed at: #list name.data as element  [in template "report.ftl" at line 33, column 9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to create a getter for `data`. Form the [docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html):

> Note that public fields are not visible directly; you must write a getter method for them.

Comment: Or one can set `exposeFields` to `true` in `BeansWrapper`, though the Java-ish way is adding a getter, so I would also recommend that.

Comment: I chose the getter way: added getX method for each field and now it's working!Thanks for the help!